# Best way to set enviroment variables for all processes

Tags: environment-variables

What is the best and standard way for setting env vars in Linux so they are visible for all processes (and users) ?

Is adding them to  `/etc/environment` the best practice ?

Comment: What Unix are you using?

Comment: I am interested in generic Unix way. If there is not then generic Linux answer is next :)